# Различные результаты одного и того же кода

Tags: opencv

Есть код, считающий проходящих в автобус пассажиров. Код рабочий, НО!
Мы получаем разные результаты на разных типах компьютеров!!!
Код работает под Линукс. На персональных компьютерах мы имеем одинаковые результаты, а на рабочих устройствах (АРМ процессоры - тоже под Линукс) - совсем другие. Прогоняем и там и там одни и те же видеоролики. Код написан в QT с использованием OpenCV. 
Версии библиотек на персональных компьютерах и на таргетт устройствах разные...

Comment: Так может стоит синхронизировать тогда версии библиотек и проверить получаемый результат?

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову - какие-то объекты считаются/распознаются как люди. Возможно из-за того, что разные версии библиотеки

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема? Берите в руки отладчик и выясняйте, что конкретно работает не одинаково. Вы ведь не думаете, что мы, не имея вашего кода и не тратя пару часов времени на отладку, сможем угадать причину?